# SSMS and Dynamic spreadsheet query update

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a 2013 excel dynamic spread sheet. It is using a query that is linked to SQL Server Management Studio. There is a DateTime line in the sql query that I want to update with a specific date every time the dynamic spread sheet is opened/refreshed. It seems to me that there is a way to add a pop up window that will ask for a date which will then update the sql query. Thank you for any input.

Comment: Is the specific date you're updating the current date? Can you use the current date/time from either the server (SQL Server) or the client (Excel)?

Comment: It is not the current date. It is a report that is looking for data in a particular month. So it could be from last month or the month before.